# Table View Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, programación-móvil

Soy nueva programando para iOS por lo que no se como resolver este problema, tengo una vista donde tengo 2 tableview uno donde selecciona que chat desea abrir y el otro table es donde se muestran los mensajes. Ahora tengo 3 problemas

1. A la hora de seleccionar el chat no se muestran mis mensajes automáticamente (Refresh) si no hasta seleccionar el tableview chat
2. A la hora de enviar un mensaje no muestra el globito gris e igual intente refrescarlo y ni así solo me elimina los mensajes
3. Que cada vez que se envie un mensaje o te muestre el chat se muestre el ultimo mensaje

---

Este es mi código del table View

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     var cell:UITableViewCell?
    if tableView == self.tableView2 {
            let tu = ((identificador[indexPath.row])as NSString).integerValue
            if tu == 2{
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Messages",  for: indexPath) as! ChatTableViewCell
                    cell.emisor.isHidden = true
                    cell.receptortxt.text = self.chats[indexPath.row]
                    return cell
            }
            else if tu == 1{
                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Messages",  for: indexPath) as! ChatTableViewCell
                    cell.receptor.isHidden = true
                    cell.emisortxt.text = self.chats[indexPath.row]
                    return cell
            }
    }
    if tableView == self.tableView {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
            cell?.textLabel?.text=separated[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell!
}
```

---

Este es el código al seleccionar chat

```
 func peticionhttp()
{
   /// Codigo que manda a traer cual chat
             self.refresh()
             self.boton.setTitle("\(self.separated[0])", for: .normal)
             }
        }
        task.resume()
}
func refresh(){
    print("refreshed" , tu2)
    self.tableView2.reloadData()
    self.tableView2.separatorStyle = .none
}
```

---

Código al enviar mensaje

```
@IBAction func onClicEnviar(_ sender: Any) {
   // dismissKeyboard()
    peticionhttpcuatro()

    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pulsa para refrescar")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ChatIndividual.refrescar), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

    tableView2.addSubview(refresher)
}


 @objc func refrescar () {
    chats.append(textfield.text!)
    identificador += ["1"]

    tableView2.reloadData()
    refresher.endRefreshing()
    print(chats,identificador,"Heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeey ")
}
```

---

*P.d: No estoy utilizando Firebase*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inteta llamar tu funcion self.refresh en el main thread ya que todas las operaciones que intenten modificar UI deben ejecutarce en este hilo.
1-

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
  self.refresh()
}
```

2- En este caso todos tus mensajes deben estar en un arreglo, cuando envias el mensaje inserta ese mensaje en tu arrelgo y en la tabla:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: <#T##[IndexPath]#>, with: <#T##UITableViewRowAnimation#>)
 tableView.endUpdates()
```

Ejemplo:

import UIKit

class ChatCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var senderMessage: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var receiverMessage: UILabel!

```
static let idenfitier: String = String(describing: ChatCell.self)

var message: Message?{
    didSet{
        if let unwrappedMessage = message{
            if unwrappedMessage.sender == 1{
                senderMessage.text = unwrappedMessage.message
                receiverMessage.text = ""
            }else{
                receiverMessage.text = unwrappedMessage.message
                senderMessage.text = ""
            }
        }
    }
}
}

struct Message {
    var message: String?
    var sender: Int?
//    2 = receptor, 1 = emisor
}

class ChatViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var chatView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var messageTextField: UITextField!

var messages = [Message(message: "Hola", sender: 2), Message(message: "Hola, ¿Comó estas?", sender: 1)]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    chatView.delegate = self
    chatView.dataSource = self
    chatView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
    chatView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
    chatView.separatorStyle = .none
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ChatCell.idenfitier) as! ChatCell

    cell.message = messages[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}

@IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: UIButton){
    if let text = messageTextField.text{
        let newMessage = Message(message: text, sender: 1)
        messages.append(newMessage)
        chatView.reloadData()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Muchas Graciaaaas eso resolvió mi primer problema ,
intente aplicarlo en mi segundo problema sin embargo me elimina todos los globos de chat :/

Comment: No entindi bien el segundo problema

Comment: Puedes poner el codigo donde agregas el nuevo mensaje?

Comment: A la hora en que escribes un mensaje y le das enviar supuestamente te tiene que aparecer el globito de chat con el mensaje y pues eso no lo hace al contrario elimina todos los globos del chat

Comment: Ya vi lo que pasa, en este caso no debes refrescar la tabla, solo debes insertar el nuevo row:

Comment: modifique la respuesta

Comment: ¿Y cómo hago para especificar que lo quiero en el globo del emisor? perdona tanta molestia pero soy nueva en esto :(

Comment: Como lo haces actualmente?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a cómo defino si es emisor y receptor?

Comment: si, como lo haces ahorita, o como ordenas esos mensajes que estan el la captura ?

Comment: están en la pregunta... es el primer código... ahí hago la condición   si el mensaje proviene del emisor (1) o del receptor (2)...

Comment: preparare un ejemplo de como hacerlo de otra forma, ya creo que asi como lo estas haciendo es mas dificil de lo que es

Comment: ¿Y en donde podría ver ese ejemplo?

Comment: ya lo agregue, revisalo

Comment: Vale muchas Gracias pero muchas Gracias! ;)

Comment: oye amigo... ¿Crees poder pasarme tu correo para hacerte unas cuantas preguntas?